# Ionic native scrolling does not continue to show the whole screen view iOS

Tags: ios, html, ionic-framework

Having I am having a problem with Ionic native scrolling it does not continue to show the whole screen view

here my simple page view connected to API..

```
                  <!--Emporia Home-->
      <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <ion-view name="home-view">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button style="color:white" class="button icon button-clear" ng-click="toggleLeft()"> <font face="emporia2" style="color:white" size="5">h</font></button>
          <button style="color:white" class="button icon button-clear" ng-click="toggleLeft()"> &nbsp; EMPORIA</font></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
          <button style="color:white" class="button icon button-clear" ng-href="#/cart"> <font face="emporia2" style="color:white" size="5">a&nbsp;</font></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>

        <ion-content ng-controller="homeCtrl" overflow-scroll=”true” scroll="true">
          <div class="item item-image">
            <ion-slide-box delegate-handle="image-viewer" on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" does-continue="true" show-pager="false">
              <ion-slide ng-repeat="board in billboard">
                <a>
                  <img ng-src="{{board.banner_image_url}}" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                </a>
              </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="item item-image">

              <a href="#/men">
                <img ng-src="{{hisStyle[0].full_image_url}}" class="col col-50 hisStyle" height="150px" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                <p class="hisLabel">{{hisStyle[0].name}}</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#/women">
                <img ng-src="{{herStyle[0].full_image_url}}" class="col col-50 herStyle" height="150px" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                <p class="herLabel">{{herStyle[0].name}}</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="try item item-image">
            <ion-slide-box delegate-handle="image-viewer" on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" does-continue="true" show-pager="false">
              <ion-slide>
                <a href="#/accesories">
                  <img ng-src="{{category[0].full_image_url}}" class="hi col col-50" height="150px" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                  <p class="category1Label">{{category[0].name}}</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#/bag">
                  <img ng-src="{{category[1].full_image_url}}" class="hello col col-50" height="150px" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                  <p class="category2Label">{{category[1].name}}</p>
                </a>
              </ion-slide>
              <ion-slide>
                <a href="#/clothing">
                  <img ng-src="{{category[2].full_image_url}}" class="hi col col-50" height="150px" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                  <p class="category1Label">{{category[2].name}}</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#/eyewear">
                  <img ng-src="{{category[3].full_image_url}}" class="hello col col-50" height="150px" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                  <p class="category2Label">{{category[3].name}}</p>
                </a>
              </ion-slide>
              <ion-slide>
                <div>
                  <a href="#/footwear">
                    <img ng-src="{{category[4].full_image_url}}" class="hi col col-50" height="150px" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                    <p class="category1Label">{{category[4].name}}</p>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#/eyewear">
                    <img ng-src="{{category[3].full_image_url}}" class="hello col col-50" height="150px" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                    <p class="category2Label">{{category[3].name}}</p>
                  </a>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide-box>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <div collection-repeat="brand in brands" class="col col-50">
                  <div class="bg item item-image">
                    <img ng-src="{{brand.full_image_url}}" height="150px" onerror="this.src = 'img/ic_noimage_portrait.png';">
                    <p class="brand1">Brand Name</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ion-content>
```

please guid me what to do..thank you..al most all of my page got this issue and I only give one as a example..